# python cgi.escape encoding question

Tags: python, escaping

I'm using cgi.escape for a Django project, to protect from XSS attacks.

The protection works well, and my escaped content appears well on browsers, BUT if I read the html it is something like this:

```
<p>&Sigma;&epsilon; &mu;&alpha;&gamma;&iota;&kappa;ό &tau;&alpha;&xi;ί&delta;&iota; &mu;&epsilon; &pi;&rho;&omicron;&omicron;&rho;&iota;&sigma;&mu;ό &tau;&eta;&nu; &Pi;ό&lambda;&eta; &kappa;&alpha;&iota; &tau;&iota;&sigmaf; &sigma;&upsilon;&gamma;&kappa;&iota;&nu;ή&sigma;&epsilon;&iota;&sigmaf; &pi;&omicron;&upsilon; &xi;&upsilon;&pi;&nu;ά, &mu;&alpha;&sigmaf; &kappa;&alpha;&lambda;&epsilon;ί &sigma;&tau;&omicron; &Pi;&alpha;&lambda;&lambda;ά&sigmaf; &eta; &Epsilon;&upsilon;&alpha;&nu;&theta;ί&alpha; &Rho;&epsilon;&mu;&pi;&omicron;ύ&tau;&sigma;&iota;&kappa;&alpha; &sigma;&tau;&iota;&sigmaf; &alpha;&rho;&chi;έ&sigmaf; &tau;&omicron;&upsilon; &nu;έ&omicron;&upsilon; &chi;&rho;ό&nu;&omicron;&upsilon;.&nbsp;</p>
```

Obviously this cannot be read from search engines and it creates a big problem for my project.  This seems to be an issue for non english content.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: Why do you think it cannot be read by a search engine? I'm not familiar, but if the engine uses any HTML/SGML/XML parser, it replaces entities.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [html meta tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) to insert keywords and other interesting searchable content.